# What does present participle "occurring throughout most of North America" modify?

Tags: present-participles

> Raccoons have a vast transcontinental distribution, occurring throughout most of North America and Central America. (From TOEFL)

Is the logic subject of "occuring" transcontinental distribution, or Raccoons?

How to I distinguish them?

Comment: You can only distinguish them semantically, not formally. _Raccoons_ occur in places. The _distribution_ is already qualified as _transcontinental_, but it just is, it isn't in a place.

Comment: Raccoons don't occur. They don't happen. Events occur. Can a distribution occur? Maybe, but the sentence is better without the word! "Raccoons have a vast transcontinental distribution throughout most of North America and Central America."

Comment: It doesn't modify anything. It's a supplementary adjunct, a non-modifier.